# windows phone smtp mail not working

Tags: uwp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm using this below DLL to send the email from windows phone apps.

https://github.com/LightBuzz/SMTP-WinRT

but unfortunately

A certificate chain processed but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800B0109)

the error will come.

I have copied my certificate to Trusted root certification authorities using MMC too. when I use Gmail or outlook server, it working good.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: It seems when you use Gmail or outlook server, there is no exception. What server do you use when it throw exception?

Comment: I would check the urls certificate with a free tool like this.  https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html  it might tell you what is wrong with the certificate

Comment: Its a kind of check issue in dll for third party . I have modified the git code as per my need. Now Its working good.